# How to sort a list that contains inner lists by the inner lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, lis

I have a list that contains lists, examples:

```
table[0] = ['255.255.255.255', '58267', '233', 'ESTABLISHED']
table[1] = ['255.132.0.0', '38367', '273', 'CLOSED']
```

I want to sort the list 'table' by the inner list, example:

I would like to sort 'table' by alphabetical order accordingly to the string that is placed in the last index in the list that is placed in every index in 'table'. It would look like this:

```
table[0] = ['255.132.0.0', '38367', '273', 'CLOSED']
table[1] = ['255.255.255.255', '58267', '233', 'ESTABLISHED']
```

They changed places because 'C' comes before 'E'.

I tried this:

```
table.sort(key=lambda x: x.sort())
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
table.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1])

print(table)
```

Output:

```
[['255.132.0.0', '38367', '273', 'CLOSED'], ['255.255.255.255', '58267', '233', 'ESTABLISHED']]
```

Comment: @Maya could you please summarize the explanation. I am confused too about how this works?

Comment: So I think that the code sorts 'table' by what is placed in the last place of the inner list (x = inner list, x[-1] = last place of the inner list). The default sort is by alphabetical order :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use `numpy`'s `argsort()` function.
It returns the indexes in the order how they would be after sorting.

```
import numpy as np
table = [['255.255.255.255', '58267', '233', 'ESTABLISHED'], ['255.132.0.0', '38367', '273', 'CLOSED']]

sorted_indexes = np.argsort([row[-1] for row in table])

sorted_table = np.array(table)[sorted_indexes]
# as list (and not numpy array):
sorted_table.tolist()

# [['255.132.0.0', '38367', '273', 'CLOSED'],
#  ['255.255.255.255', '58267', '233', 'ESTABLISHED']]
```

But the good thing with `np.argsort()` is that it also works with Pandas dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(table)

sorted_indexes = np.argsort(df.iloc[:, -1])

sorted_df = df.iloc[sorted_indexes, :]

sorted_df                                                                                             

#                  0      1    2            3
# 1      255.132.0.0  38367  273       CLOSED
# 0  255.255.255.255  58267  233  ESTABLISHED

# you can get numpy arrays by `.values`
# and from numpy array to normal lists by `.tolist()
# so:

sorted_df.values.tolist() 

# [['255.132.0.0', '38367', '273', 'CLOSED'],
#  ['255.255.255.255', '58267', '233', 'ESTABLISHED']]
```

But Pandas has of course built-in sort:

```
df.sort_values(by=[3])
```

And you can give for `by` several column names or column indexes, which determine the priority column values for the sorting.
Using `.values.tolist()` you can re-transform the data frame back to simple lists.

Comment: Oh I'm not that advanced in python haha but thank you!

Comment: @Maya for dealing with tables - you should learn `pandas` data frames as quickly as possible. It will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @Maya tutorials in youtube by Corey Schafer e.g. are excellent to get introduced quickly

Comment: Noted! Thank you!